# How to change the language of a WebDriver?

Tags: webdriver, locale, selenium-webdriver

I want to execute my Selenium tests in different languages. Is it possible to change the language of an existing WebDriver at runtime or do I have to recreate the browser instance?

Right now I'm only using Firefox, but I want to execute tests in different browsers at some later point.

In Firefox I set the language like this:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "de");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I also implemented a WebDriverPool, which holds a WebDriver instance so it can be shared among tests. If the language can only be set at creation time, I could hold an instance for every locale.

All in all I wonder if I miss something here. Why is it so hard to change the language? shouldn't there be a method like `WebDriver.setAcceptLanguages(Locale)`?

In a nutshell I have these questions:

1. Why isn't there `WebDriver.setAcceptLanguages(Locale)`?
2. How to change the language for the dirrerent WebDrivers?
3. Can I change the language at runtime?
4. How did you guys implement your WebDriverPool or do you recreate them everytime?

Comment: I can think of several scenarios: Check date and number formatting and input for different locales, take screenshots in different languages, maybe show some hint if someone with an unsupported language comes along and so on. I would argue, if your webapp supports multiple languages testing it in multiple can make sense for some test cases, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up creating a WebDriverPool that creates one instance for every combination of WebDriver type (e.g. FirefoxDriver.class) and Locale (e.g. en_US). Maybe this is usful for someone.

```
public class WebDriverPool {

  private Map<String, WebDriver> drivers = new HashMap<String, WebDriver>();
  private List<WebDriver> driversInUse = new ArrayList<WebDriver>();

  public WebDriverPool() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
        for (WebDriver driver : drivers.values())
          driver.close();

        if (!driversInUse.isEmpty())
          throw new IllegalStateException("There are still drivers in use, did someone forget to return it? (size: " + driversInUse.size() + ")");
      }
    });
  }

  private WebDriver createFirefoxDriver(Locale locale){
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", formatLocale(locale));
    return new FirefoxDriver(profile);
  }

  private String formatLocale(Locale locale) {
    return locale.getCountry().length() == 0
      ? locale.getLanguage()
      : locale.getLanguage() + "-" + locale.getCountry().toLowerCase();
  }

  /**
   * @param clazz
   * @param locale
   * @return web driver which can be new or recycled
   */
  public synchronized WebDriver getWebDriver(Class<? extends WebDriver> clazz, Locale locale){

    String key = clazz.getName() + "-" + locale;

    if(!drivers.containsKey(key)){

      if(clazz == FirefoxDriver.class){
        drivers.put(key, createFirefoxDriver(locale));
      }

      // TODO create other drivers here ...

      // else if(clazz == ChromeDriver.class){
      //     drivers.put(key, createChromeDriver(locale));
      // }

      else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(clazz.getName() + " not supported yet!");
      }
    }

    WebDriver driver = drivers.get(key);

    if(driversInUse.contains(driver))
      throw new IllegalStateException("This driver is already in use. Did someone forgot to return it?");

    driversInUse.add(driver);
    return driver;
  }

  public synchronized void returnWebDriver(WebDriver driver){
    driversInUse.remove(driver);
  }
}
```

Comment: I like that class but I don't get why you evaluate which WebDriver is in use... May I have your explanation?

Comment: @Frank: Your question is, why the Class<> clazz is a parameter to the "getWebDriver" method? This is because the calling test class can decide what kind of driver should be created. We need this, because there are tests for InternetExplorer only, this ActiveX is used.

Comment: No I don't get why you log if a driver is in use (private List<WebDriver> driversInUse) ... is that just for closing them properly?

Comment: Yes, this is just for helping the developers to close all browsers properly.

Comment: Can you tell me how to achieve that different testclasses can reach the same WebDriverPool? Do you pass it along with a DataProvider?

Comment: @Frank: I implemented the pool as a singleton

Comment: so multithreading tests with the same setup is not designated right!?

Comment: That's correct. I don't run tests in parallel right now. Maybe I extend the pool to support multithreading in the future.

Comment: what I additionally did, was to set "general.useragent.locale" to the language I wanted it to have.

Comment: @markus: what does this change? the language firefox is displayed in? For my purpose the ´intl.accept_languages´ was the only thing needed, but if it makes sense I could edit my example.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it through about:config in firefox. But you need to use Actions to manipulate it.

Below a java piece of code

```
    Actions act = new Actions(webDriver);          

    webDriver.get("about:config");

    // warning screen
    act.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();

    // Go directly to the list, don't use the search option, it's not fast enough
    act.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).perform();

    // Go to the intl.accept_languages option
    act.sendKeys("intl.accept_languages").sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();

    // fill the alert with your parameters
    webDriver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("fr, fr-fr, en-us, en");
    webDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: after `act.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();` gives me `UnreachableBrowserException` with webDriver3

Comment: @LanMan I've no problem with webDriver3, but about:config interface has changed. The actions must be rewritten according to the Firefox version.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid that the whole idea of WebDriver is **to act like browser** - so you can change the language of the browser, but you have to change the locale in the Operating system, or hope that the application will do it for you.

For instance - German number format separates decimal number by comma and English one by dot. If you want to test, how the number format behaves in English locale and in German locale, you can do it only by these two approaches:

1. Change OS locale from German to English or vice versa
2. Change browser language and hope that application will change the behavior.

To answer your questions:

1. There is no setLocale on Webdriver, because WebDriver simulates browser, not OS
2. I would do it like this (Java code):

   ```
   private WebDriver driver;  

   public enum Language {en-us, de}

   public WebDriver getDriver(Language lang){
     String locale = lang.toString();
     FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
     profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", locale);
     driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);   
     return driver;       
   }

   @Test
   public void TestNumber(){
     WebDriver drv = getDriver(Language.en);
     drv.get("http://the-site.com");
     WebElement el = drv.findElement //... find element
     String number = el.getText();
     Assert.assertEquals(number, "123.45");
     drv.close();
     drv = getDriver(Language.de);
     drv.get("http://the-site.com");
     WebElement el = drv.findElement //... find element
     String number = el.getText();
     Assert.assertEquals(number, "123,45");
     drv.close();
   }
   ```
3. I am afraid you have to close the browser and open it again with different language.
4. I personally create new instance of the browser for each test.

BTW the above bit of code assumes, that the web application changes the way how to show numbers to the user based on browser language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly that doesn't help me much. You say the locale can only be changed at the OS level, that is not true. You can change the locale in Firefox or Chrome while running and with the next request, the "accept_languages" in the http header is changed. Our application uses this language to choose texts and formats numbers and dates.

Comment: Secondly, recreating the browser instance each time is very slow. You should think about implementing a pool for that.

Comment: To affect the value of the `Accept-Language`-Header in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, it is sufficient to change the language settings inside the browser and reload a page without modifying any OS settings.