# Selenium change firefox browser language python mac

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I've spent 3 hours trying to find a solution to this problem, and I'm so far from an answer I feel like I have to ask. (I've found similar posts - below is an explanation of why I'm asking despite finding these posts)

I'm writing a program that enters several search terms into google - and retrieves the ranking of my page. I want to know my ranking for several different country SERP's. I've gotten the issue with ip address solved. But now I see that google is factoring in the language of my browser when giving me a SERP. In order to get closer to the true rank of my page in a country ( I say closer because I've also seen that the SERP depends on search history) I have to use a web browser with a language native to the country I'm interested in.

Changing the language in firefox manually is difficult - as a matter of fact you have to install several different language version (I've also read about installing language packs - but unsure if this is relevant for firefox 12). I don't have a clue about how to get selenium to choose the right firefox version.

I'm having a hard time understanding what needs to be done: Do I have to specify which firefox installation / version selenium is suppose to use when launching `web driver.firefox().` Or is it possible to determine the browser language by changing the firefox profile.

I've spent some time looking into the profile part - and found partial [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822717/how-to-change-the-language-of-a-webdriver) (original post) although I can't find any reference to language in the profile files.

The answer in the same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822717/how-to-change-the-language-of-a-webdriver) seems to have solved the problem - but I don't know the language and I'm having trouble understanding what's actually being done.

I know there's an [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/) to firefox for changing between the language versions (you have to first install the different language versions of firefox that you want) - Given that the settings option mentions changing "general.useragent.local preference" I'm thinking it's a profile setting that can be changed - but the add-on requires a re-start of the browser when you change the language - so..

I can't find anything about general.useragent.local in the profile settings.

Any one giving me a point in the right direction would be making my day!

EDIT:
Forgot to mention - I only know python - so that's why I wrote python in the title

Comment: Why do this with Firefox?  It sounds like something for curl or wget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have to agree that perhaps this isnt the best way to approach this problem but will answer what you need

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('path/to/binary')
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension('path/to/xpi') #XPI needs to be on disk and not downloaded from AMO
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.local','<enter your value')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=profile)
# Carry on with what you want
```

The pydocs are available [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply AutomatedTester!!! What way would you say is the best way to approach ? do you have the same opinion as robert ?