# Why doesn’t input.send_keys() work in my Selenium WebDriver Python script when run as www-data?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, debian, selenium-webdriver

I have a Python script that uses [Selenium WebDriver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) (with [PyVirtualDisplay](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) as the display) to log into Flickr.

- http://pastebin.com/dqmf4Ecw (you’ll need to add your own Flickr credentials)

When I run it as myself on my Debian server, it works fine. (I’m a sudoer, but I don’t use sudo when running the script.)

When I run it as the user `www-data` (which is what it’ll be running as eventually, because I want to trigger it from a Django website), I get two problems, one small, one big:

1. (Small): the `webdriver.Firefox()` call takes 30–45 seconds to return, compared to 2 seconds when run as myself
2. (Big): the script fails to log into Flickr. In order to log in, I find the username and password fields on the Flickr signin page (http://www.flickr.com/signin/), and use `element.send_keys()` to enter the username and password. Although Selenium seems to find the elements (i.e. no `NoSuchElementException` is thrown), the values do not get entered in the fields when the script is run as `www-data` (according to the screenshots I take using `browser.save_screenshot`), unlike when the script is run as myself.

Why does `send_keys()` not work when the script is run as `www-data`? (And is it related to the browser taking much longer to start?)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have something different in your environment.

Try copy by example your `~/.bashrc` in `/home/www-data`

If it's not sufficient, run this command both as your current user & as `www-data`:

```
strace -tt -f -s 1000 -o /tmp/trace ./script.py
```

And paste it (filter out your logins/passwords) somewhere.

We will see what's happens.

Comment: Excellent, sounds like good troubleshooting steps. I’m not at my machine right now, but I’ll do that when I am.

Comment: Right. Copying my `~/.bashrc` file into `/home/www-data` (which I created first, as it didn’t exist) didn’t seem to have any effect: the script behaved as before when run as me and as `www-data`. I’ve installed strace on the server and run the command you suggested, but for some reason `/tmp/trace` isn’t getting created when I run the script as either user. (I get lots of output on my screen, but I don’t get a file.) Under both users, strace doesn’t seem to return once the script’s finished though — I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to get a shell prompt again.

Comment: See my edited POST, there was an error in the `strace` command line.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. Just having a look at the stack traces, as when saved to text files they ended up around 48 MB and 25 MB respectively. Should be able to get them up onto the web in some form tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe the first 100000 lines is sufficient for the moment. You can filter that out with `head -n 100000 FILE > NEW_FILE`

Comment: Gotcha. Alrighty, they’re up at http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/trace_pauldwaite_head.txt and http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/trace_www-data_head.txt

Comment: Gotcha, I will pop them up a bit later on tonight once I’m back on a proper connection.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17713/discussion-between-sputnick-and-paul-d-waite)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Firefox performs some nasty plugin compatibility check during startup. As each user can have a different set of browser plugins, this could be responsible for the difference in startup times. You could try to sync your Firefox profiles between users.

Then, are you sure that Firefox as user www-data has proper network/internet access? Can you confirm that the Flickr site loads properly via SeleniumHQ? "*The script fails to log into Flickr*" is too unprecise. Some more details about why it fails might reveal the problem instantaneously.

Edit: Sorry, I just understood that there shouldn't be a difference in profiles, because Selenium creates one. Nevertheless, my second point might be useful, so I won't delete this answer.

Comment: That’s a good point re confirming what Selenium’s doing — I’ll amend my test script to pop out some screen shots so that I can provide more detail. Hopefully plugins should’t be a problem — I installed Firefox on the Debian server using aptitude (via squeeze-backports) and otherwise left it alone, so if I understand correctly it shouldn’t have any plugins installed.

Comment: Alrighty. Having written out some screenshots whilst Selenium is controlling Firefox, it looks like the username and password are not entered into the fields on the web page when the script is run as `www-data`. I take one screenshot before I use `field.send_keys` to enter the username and password, and one after. When I run the script as me, the second screenshot has the values entered in the field. When I run the script as `www-data`, it does not.

Comment: I wonder if it’s anything to do with this bug: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2465

Answer (score 1):

Some more things to ponder about:

- Could you spawn firefox manually from www-data account once and make sure that Firefox is not updating itself before every execution of the script? I once faced this problem with Selenium RC on Windows and had to let the update finish before starting the script with the updated binary.
- As a workaround, I guess you could you try running the script as www-data user but connecting remotely to a webdriver server running in your login (aka "grid" mode). Would that work for you?

Comment: “Could you spawn firefox manually from www-data account once and make sure that Firefox is not updating itself before every execution of the script?” — Possibly. Thing is, I don’t have the password of the `www-data` account, so I don’t think I can log into the GUI as `www-data`.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you could give an explicit location to the latest version of the Firefox binary instead of letting WebDriver use the system default. Look for instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10566625/1537330

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Use `gksu -u www-data firefox` (using your own password).

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: aha! Right, that looks good — will try it and report back.

Comment: It‘s actually a bit tricky to launch Firefox from the `www-data` account, even using `gksu`. `www-data`’s home folder is `/var/www`, but it doesn’t have write permissions there. This means it can’t create a Firefox profile when Firefox launches, and thus Firefox doesn’t launch. However, I have launched Firefox from Selenium running as me, and when Selenium launches Firefox, it creates a Firefox profile in `/tmp/` (which Firefox presumably uses during its Selenium session).

Comment: Re grid mode, that’s probably a good idea, although I was hoping to avoid having to have anything running outside my Python script.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: There's a command-line switch to specify a profile directory, so specify somewhere in `/tmp/` or `/run/shm/` to bypass that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting the latest chrome from google and trying input.send_keys() in that browser instead.

Sometimes some features of webdriver get broken with new releases.. If you are bent on testing with firefox, you might have better luck with an older/newer version of selenium webdriver.

I remember having a similar issue regarding send_keys() on a mac.. My issue was that send_keys() did not work in certain modal windows after I updated selenium webdriver.. I fixed it by reverting to an older webdriver that I knew to work. However, I was using Ruby and not Python to drive webdriver.

sometimes, there might also be a problem with getting the correct ENV variables in your shell if you use it as a different user. I would suggest trying to troubleshoot and see if all the shell ENV variables are set properly under www-data.

Comment: Chrome: worth a try, I’ll give it a go. On the environment variables, any idea what particularly I might be looking for? I’ve compared my env variables with www-data’s, and there doesn’t seem to be anyting obvious or Selenium/Python-related missing for www-data.

Comment: there shouldn't be any environment variables required in particular for firefox.. but chrome does require some additional configuration (including one environment variable).. hope this helps...