# How to set browser locale in IE using Selenium Web Driver in C# project

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do you set the browser locale to different languages in a `C#`project using `Selenium Web driver`?

Use case: once I complete test execution on English language I want to set/change locale to let’s say German language and then rerun all cases once again.

Any information on this will be highly appreciated. I need to do this on `Internet Explorer`

Comment: have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822717/how-to-change-the-language-of-a-webdriver#answer-10331259

Comment: That is in Java. I need in c#

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# but here is a suggestion.  You might modify this setting in the register programmatically with C#.  I've seen it done in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java), so I guess it is also possible to do it in C#.

The regedit key is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International
```

and the parameter is `AcceptLanguage` (see [Microsoft KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919356.aspx))