# Geb driver issue after upgrading to Grails 2.4.5

Tags: grails, geb

Upon upgrading my Grails version from 2.3.6 to 2.4.5, I am now getting an exception when running Geb Spock tests.

```
failed to create driver from callback 'script14328041759692122350870$_run_closure1@5fcdf5ea'
geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script14328041759692122350870$_run_closure1@5fcdf5ea'
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:361)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:350)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
    at geb.Browser.clearCookies(Browser.groovy:496)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:54)
    at AuthorizationAdminSpec.setupSpec(AuthorizationAdminSpec.groovy:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/SchemePortResolver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:234)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at script14328041759692122350870.run_closure1(script14328041759692122350870.groovy:12)
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.SchemePortResolver
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 23 more
```

I remember encountering this exception before during my initial Geb setup in Grails 2.3.6, in which the BuildConfig and GebConfig files were not properly configured. However, upon re-checking the necessary plugins and dependencies required of Geb, I did not notice anything different for Grails 2.4.5 Also, I switched my dependency resolution from Ivy to Maven, so I double checked my maven resources to make sure the driver was loaded.

[image]

Some more info...

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"

    mavenRepo "http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo"

    mavenRepo "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"

    mavenRepo "http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/repo"

    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo"
}

dependencies {
....
    compile "org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.9.RELEASE"

    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.10.0"

    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.45.0"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.45.0"
}

plugins {
....
    test ":geb:0.10.0"
}
```

GebConfig.groovy

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile

reportsDir = "target/geb-reports"
baseUrl = "http://localhost:8090/adverity/"

driver = {
    //set the firefox locale to 'en-us' since the tests expect english
    //see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822717 for more details
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile()
    profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-us")
    def driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver(profile)
    driverInstance.manage().window().maximize()
    driverInstance
}

baseNavigatorWaiting = true
atCheckWaiting = true
autoClearCookies = false
quitCachedDriverOnShutdown = false
```

Any simple spec that I run will throw the same error.I tried doing the same with Chrome to test if this is a driver issue and got the same results. Both firefox and Chrome drivers work with Grails 2.3.6, but not 2.4.5.

- OS: Fedora 20
- Browser: Firefox 38

Places I have looked already...

- Book of Geb
- GebGrails git hub example
- StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2'
```

Added to the dependencies section in BuildConfig.groovy

I was not aware of this dependency as I did not see it in any documentation, but a deeper look inside the stack trace told me otherwise.

Comment: Looks like a httpclient version conflict to me between the one required by Selenium and the other one that is on your classpath for whatever reason. They are always really hard to track down and I've hit them many times in the past.

Comment: I'm having a similar missleading issue, could be this. Is there a nice way to track down conflicts/strange missing dependencies using IntelliJ